# React Typescript error Type '{ id: number; title: string; function(): void; }' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Lx-YlI9hlY) to try and recreate a button group with an active on and off state, but I am getting the following error as I am using typescript:

```
Type '{ id: number; title: string; function(): void; }' is not assignable to type 'null'.
```

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '../button/Button'

const ButtonGroup: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    
    const [active, setActive] = React.useState({
        activeObject: null,
        objects: [{
            id: 1 as number,
            title: '1' as string, 
            function() {
                alert('yes 1')
            }
            
        }, {
            id: 2 as number,
            title: '2' as string,
            function() {
                alert('yes 2')
            }
        }, {
            id: 3 as number,
            title: '3' as string,
            function() {
                alert('yes 3')
            }
        }]
    })

    const toggleActive = (index: number) => {
        setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })
    }

    function toggleActiveStyles(index: number) {
        if (active.objects[index] === active.activeObject) {
            return "btn-tertiary"
        } else {
            return "btn-tertiary-active"
        }
    }

    return (
        <> <div >
            {active.objects.map((inner, index) => {
                return (
                    <Button variant="btn btn-tertiary" className={toggleActiveStyles(index)} onClick={() => toggleActive(index)} key={inner.id}>{inner.title}</Button>
                )
            })}
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default ButtonGroup;
```

Any idea's?

Comment: you should use `useReducer` instead of `useState`

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: added my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because of this line

```
 const toggleActive = (index: number) => {
        setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })
    }
```

when you do `active.objects[index]` you trying to assign an object of type `{ id: number; title: string; function(): void; }` to your activeObject where the initial value is null.

You can provide the type for your state,

```
type ActiveObject = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  function(): void;
};

type ButtonGroupState = {
  activeObject: ActiveObject | null;
  objects: ActiveObject[];
};
```

And use this type in your useState

```
 const [active, setActive] = React.useState<ButtonGroupState>({ ... })
```

Comment: I get the error: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ActiveObject'.

Comment: Then you can do this  `activeObject: ActiveObject | null;` updating my answer as well .

Comment: One question how would I add the onClick function from each object to each button? as I already have put the onClick function on the button element?

Comment: So we need to call that function inside the object when w click on the button ?

Comment: Correct the objects have a function to each object

Comment: i suppose I could just update the state in the function themselves

Answer (score 3):

`useState` will default to the "type" of the parameter if you do not specify it directly.

```
const [active, setActive] = React.useState({
  activeObject: null,
  /* ... */
});
```

So in this case, `activeObject` can only be inferred as being `null` and nothing else.

Instead, I would suggest defining a `type` or `interface` and telling `useState` that is the type of the state object.

```
type AO = {
  activeObject: { id: number; title: string; function(): void; };
  /* and all of your other data */
}
```

Then

```
const [active, setActive] = React.useState<AO>({ /* ... */ });
```

Will specify that `active`'s type is `AO`. You also then do not need to do the `as number` or `as string` as those types will be *required* to be an `AO` type.

Answer (score 2):

As per [react-docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), in the case of complex state, it is better to use `useReducer` hook

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState,useReducer} = React;
function reducer(state, action) {
    return { 
        activeObject: {
        id: 1,
        title: '1', 
        function() {
            alert('yes 1')
            }
        }
    }
}
const Example = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useReducer(reducer, {
        activeObject: null
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(active)}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setActive()}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```